# Get and update data using stored procedure using mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in which I want to first get all data from a table and update the data using same stored procedure. I have tried using a variable but not able to do the same.

Please suggest some solutions for the same.

```
create procedure Std(in taskDone int)
select i.id from student join teacher
group by i.id;
update student set status = taskDone
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE checkUser(IN in_email VARCHAR(80), IN in_password VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DECLARE tempId INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tempName VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE email = in_email AND password = in_password;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur;

    REPEAT
        FETCH cur INTO tempId, tempName;
        UPDATE users SET online = 1 WHERE id = tempId;
    UNTIL done  = 1 END REPEAT;
    CLOSE cur;

    SELECT tempName;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```